# Page Up / Page Down shortcut keys with moving keyboard cursor

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I am trying to find an equivalent to Page Up / Page Down keys on a Windows machine. On a Windows machine if I press Page Up or Page Down in a text editor (such as Microsoft Word or notepad++) the keyboard cursor moves as well.

The closest I found on a MacBook is to use FN + Arrow Up or FN + Arrow Down. This does do Page Up / Page Down for viewing. However, it does not move the keyboard cursor. How do I get the keyboard cursor to move a page up or down?

Comment: Have a look at Apples help page here   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: @Junme I've looked at that one already. Is there something specific on that page you were wanting me to look at or were you just sending me a random page of shortcut keys?

Comment: the link refers to the general document navigation shortcuts, you haven't said which program you are referring to either for windows or mac I can only presume a text editor  maybe you could add a bit more detail to your question

Comment: @Junme For any program that has keyboard input spanning multiple pages. This includes all text editors. So on Windows it could include Microsoft Word, notepad, notepad++, etc. On MacOS it could include textEdit, Xcode, etc. Also, it is not helpful to provide random links that have no use in answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

I found that if I do:

```
FN + Option + Up Arrow
```

or

```
FN + Option + Down Arrow
```

this does move the keyboard cursor a page up or down. It's still a bit clunkier than how things work on Windows, but it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`⌥ + page up` and `⌥ + page down` works, too.